# How to get ALPHA symbol using Google keyboard?

Tags: gboard

I want to type Symbol of aplha but I couldn't figure out how to get it , however I can type ß(Beta). But not alpha.

Comment: Why not just copy it from here, and paste when you need to when you're typing

Comment: @Cup of Java Then I have to do each time , Which is pain you know

Comment: realistically, how often are you going to use the α symbol?

Comment: @Cup of Java You got the point but still...

Comment: IIRC, what you're typing is **not** Greek 'beta' at all which should look like [β]. What you **actually** typed may be German 'ss'. LOL.

Comment: @iBug Lol oh ok I didn't knew that anyway doing copy paste now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have superuser(root) access, install xposed framework. Search for an xposed module called 'Google Keyboard Custom Smilies' (GKCS) and install it. Open GKCS app and add 'α' symbol in it. You can use your own labels for inputs.

Comment: Any other way for Non-rooted device?

Comment: @ShubhamWagh Be simple. Grab another IME.

Answer (score 0):

Use greek language.

Tap and hold space button for quick accsess.